# Issue with highcharts stacked area chart

Tags: highcharts, stacked-area-chart

The stacked area chart in the figure has 10 series of data. But the data is all nulls for the last four series. The color in the chart for series 6 is rendered incorrectly.

[image: Stacked area chart for 24 hours]
After zooming the graph looks acceptable. The graph with out zooming is rendered incorrectly. The chart works alright when data is there for all series.

[image: Above graph zoomed in]

Is this an issue with highcharts ? Is this anyway related to [this issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1408)

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, thanks.

Comment: I spent a few minutes trying to recreate your issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/ppjosu49/, I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: +1 @Mark for creating the demo. I was using a previous version of High charts, the latest version doesn't seem to have any problems.